# drupal 6 - unset previously set cck field validation error messages

Tags: drupal-6, validation, cck

How can I unset previously set cck field validation error messages? Some module is setting the  form validation messages, that I want to override. In my case, it's cck_phone module.

Something like `form_unset_error($field['field_name'])` to unset the error messages?

Answer (score 1):

one way to unset the error is unset($_SESSION['messages']['error']['cck field']).
But i dont know whether it is the best way to do or not .

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the errors then clear 'drupal form static cache' if it is the last error.

```
form_set_error(NULL, '', TRUE);
```

in order to reset the state of the form. e.g.

```
$found_error = array_search('This e-mail has already been taken by another user.',    $_SESSION['messages']['error']);
if ($found_error !== FALSE) {
unset($_SESSION['messages']['error'][$found_error]);
if (sizeof($_SESSION['messages']['error']) == 0) {
      unset($_SESSION['messages']['error']);
      form_set_error(NULL, '', TRUE);
 }
```